# 1 ATI Radeon card in PCIe 2.0 slot for display. How to make use of AMD FireStream cards placed in empty PCIe 2.0 slots?

Tags: discussion, questions

> I have an AMD ATX board with 4+ PCIe 2.0 slots. 1 of the slots is
>   occupied by a ATI Radeon card which handles display. There are at
>   least 3 empty PCIe 2.0 slots on this ATX board. Suppose some [AMD
>   FireStream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_FireStream#Overview) cards were put into those empty slots. How do you take
>   advantage of the computational power of the new FireStream cards? For example, is
>   there some FireStream driver that controls the load balancing of numeric
>   computations across the CPU and all the other FireStream cards?

Is this question on topic? Has it been asked and answered here?

Comment: This does not belong on meta.

Comment: I suggest instead of asking if you can ask a question, just ask it. Unless you have lots of downvoted and closed questions, a closed question won't matter.

Comment: Can we move this to the main site please? Push it out there, into the deep dark, unchanted waters of SU, and see what happens. It will either float like a pirate ship or sink like a moai rock.

Comment: He's asking if the question is ontopic for SU. Read beyond the title

Comment: @sammyg I've seen a lot of questions like this in SU which have answers. So this can be answered there too.

Comment: @Sathya Who? Me? I did read beyond the title. I just don't understand why he is afraid to just post it on the main site and observe what happens. I don't see how this fits on meta. If everyone did what he did, the point of meta would be lost. How can he expect this to have been asked and answered before, when it's such a case specific question (for meta). And asked where, on meta or on main site? If main, then he should have done a search first to answer his own wondering. I view this as off-topic for meta, but on-topic for main (I mean the core question, not the "question about question").

Comment: @sammyg it fits meta because it's about asking if particular question is ontopic for the site.  Point we're trying to tell him is that it's not alright to do this every single time. I don't really understand why you want to push "is this on topic" question to main site.

Comment: @sammyg - you've convinced me to move this question to the main site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It seems like an interesting question. I'd be inclined to answer it.
- It's on-topic.
- I don't think it's been asked here, though I may be wrong (SU has way too many questions for me to sort through).

In general however, rather than posting your exact question on meta asking if it's on-topic before asking it on the main site, you should just post it on the main site. If you have doubt about a specific topic area and want to discuss whether it's on topic, you can ask that here.

The reason I'm discouraging you from posting this entire question on meta is that, if everyone did what you just did, every single question on the main site would have a corresponding meta question asking "is this on topic and not a duplicate?" -- which would kind of defeat the purpose of meta.

Comment: Agreed. Ask on Meta if you think your question was wrongfully closed. Or how to improve it. After the fact anyways.

Comment: I don't get it... Where is his question that was supposedly closed? If he is asking preemptively, before the fact... then what's the point of it all? If everyone did that, then that would definitely defeat the purpose of meta.

Comment: @sammyg The point is that he *hasn't* (yet) asked this question on SuperUser, so I'm explaining to him why he shouldn't do this.

Comment: @allquixotic: the general consensus appears to be to just post my question on the main site, and let the votes (up, down, or to close) sort out whether the question was on-topic.

Comment: The downvotes and overall negative reactions I often get on *this* site (in particular versus other StackExchange sites), discourages me from bothering to try even asking here. From *my* interpretation of the SuperUser Help and FAQ, I've put questions on SuperUser, with a sincere belief they were on-topic but instead just get downvotes or closed...or I just close the question if the reaction's that bad.

Often my questions are "specific" to Microsoft software, so as I get pushed away from asking on SuperUser, I start joining the  Microsoft forums.